# Null Pointer Exception on Alert dialog box

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting null pointer exception when I click on the add button. It is on line number 39 that is on this `AlertDialog.Builder a1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c)` line

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calci extends Activity {
    TextView t1;
    EditText e1, e2;
    Button add, sub, mul, div;
    Context c;

    String b, a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calci);
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
        mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
        div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        a = e1.getText().toString();
        b = e2.getText().toString();
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (a.matches("") || b.matches("")){
                AlertDialog.Builder a1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);


                // Setting Dialog Title
                a1.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                a1.setMessage("PLEASE ENTER SOMETHING");

                a1.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int button1) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                        });

                // Showing Alert Message
                AlertDialog alertDialog = a1.create();
                a1.show();

            }


            int result = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));


    }

});
    }
}
```

Comment: write this instead of "c" and check it. OR Calci.this.

Comment: Why are posting your all questions in Capital letters??

Comment: Did given answers helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize the `Context` object `c`. Now, Initialize the `c` as below...

```
Context c = this;
```

Or, as below...

```
Context c = Calci.this;
```

If you don't want to use `Context` object `c` then initialize the `AlertDialog.Builder` as below...

```
AlertDialog.Builder a1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Calci.this);
```

Comment: Maybe Context c = Calci.this; would be batter. Wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

change line 39 to:

```
AlertDialog.Builder a1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```